# Obtain the bytes of a class loaded by the boostrap class loader?

Tags: java, classloader

I would like to know if it is possible to get the bytes of a class loaded by the bootstrap class loader. Everywhere I look, people suggest to get the bytes of an arbitrary class, one must simply do

```java
Class.forName(className).getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(className.replace('.', '/') + ".class");
```

And then read the `InputStream` with a method of your choice, however this is not possible on classes loaded by the bootstrap class loader (such as `java.lang.Object`), as for those classes `Class#getClassLoader()` returns `null`.

```java
> Class.forName("java.lang.Object").getClassLoader()

null
```

Is this even possible? I've heard it can be done with instrumentation but I'm hoping there's a "better" way to do it (outside of locating `rt.jar` in the Java installation and reading the class data from there or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. You just have to get the system class loader from `ClassLoader#getSystemClassLoader()`.

```java
ClassLoader loader = Class.forName(className).getClassLoader();
if (loader == null) loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
final URL url = loader.getResourceAsStream(className.replace('.', '/') + ".class");
// read...
```